# Implementing "include" functionality via PyYAML & custom tags

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

I am attempting to implement YAML syntax like follows:

```
---
foo: bar
baz: buff
!Include: other/file
```

and have it processed at load time by PyYAML so that contents of `other/file.yml`:

```
---
special: value
```

is merged with contents of the original file, producing:

```
---
foo: bar
baz: buff
special: value
```

so far I've followed [PyYAML Docs](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Constructorsrepresentersresolvers) and [Creating Custom Tag in PyYAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058050/creating-custom-tag-in-pyyaml#43060743) and was able to get somewhat awkward implementation:

```
---
foo: bar
baz: buff
included: !Include other/file
```

which translates into:

```
---
foo: bar
baz: buff
included:
  special: value
```

I see that in [PyYAML Docs](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Constructorsrepresentersresolvers) top-level tag is being generated and it works (Monster) but my code is failing when I try to go that route:

```
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a simple key
  in "sample.yml", line 4, column 1
could not find expected ':'
  in "sample.yml", line 5, column 1
```

Current code:

```py
import yaml
import sys
from UserDict import UserDict


class Include(yaml.YAMLObject, UserDict):
    yaml_tag = u'!Include'

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        data = {}
        try:
            with open(self.path+'.yml', 'r') as f:
                data = yaml.load(f)
        except IOError:
            data = {}
        self.data = data

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{0}(path={1})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.path)

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, loader, node):
        return Include(node.value).data

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, dumper, data):
        return dumper.represent_scalar(cls.yaml_tag, data.path)

yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor(u'!Include', Include.from_yaml)
yaml.add_constructor(u'!Include', Include.from_yaml)
# Required for safe_dump
yaml.SafeDumper.add_multi_representer(Include, Include.to_yaml)
yaml.add_multi_representer(Include, Include.to_yaml)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fname = sys.argv[1]
    f = open(fname, 'r')
    data = yaml.safe_load(f)
    print("{0}".format(str(data)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tagging means the same in YAML as in the real world: that you supply some object with a tag. And a tag is not a replacement for that object.

When you do this: `!Include: other/file`, that is equivalent to doing `!Include Null: other/file`. And when parsing that `Null` node, you don't have access to `other/file`, it is not parsed and it might not even have been scanned yet.

When parsing `included: !Include other/file`, the node `other/file` does **not** have a concept of its context. It could be e.g in the form of a stack, from which you could access the latest object, but that is now how PyYAML is implemented.
The implication of this is that if you do this, you can only replace the tagged node with the datastructure loaded from the include file.

What you could do is define a "special key", e.g `+<` and then put the `!Include` tag on the mapping:

```
!Include
foo: bar
baz: buff
+<: other/file
```

With that you can implement the constructor for the mapping to create a dict, but when encountering the special key, use the keys associated value as the name of a file to load and insert as additional key/values in the dict you are building (so you don't have to access some non-available context node). You would have to come up with some way to resolve the priority of keys that come from in the included file and those that come from the actual including mapping. You could implement multiple includes by allowing the value to be a list of filenames. This is similar to the [merge key language independent type](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html) does.

You could even do the above without using a tag at all, by adding a resolver for `+<` (take the one for the merge feature as an example), subclassing the `SafeLoader` and implementing the `flatten_mapping` method to support this inclusion. That would mean however that it is not as immediately obvious for 
others that something special is going as when there is a tag.

Please note:

- you should leave out the directive-end-seperator (`---`), it is superfluous as you don't have any directives.
- your YAML files should have the extension `.yaml` [unless that is not possible](http://yaml.org/faq.html) (e.g. because the filesystem doesn't support suffixes longer than three characters)

---

In ruamel.yaml you could implement this using:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from pathlib import Path

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe', pure=True)

yaml_str = """\
!Include
foo: bar
baz: buff
+<: other/file.yaml
"""

class Include:
    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        mapping = constructor.construct_mapping(node)
        file_names = mapping.get('+<')
        if file_names is None:
            return mapping
        if not isinstance(file_names, list):
            file_names = [file_names]
        y = constructor.loader
        yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ=y.typ, pure=y.pure)
        for file_name in file_names:
            for key, value in yaml.load(Path(file_name)).items():
                if key in mapping:
                    continue
                mapping[key] = value
        return mapping


yaml.register_class(Include)

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(data)
```

which gives:

```
{'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'buff', '+<': 'other/file.yaml', 'special': 'value'}
```

in PyYAML you should be able to do something similar, with more code
and only supporting the YAML 1.1 specification (that was superseded in 2009).

Comment: Would you mind sharing some (pseudo) code to illustrate? I've attempted to use existing python code and apply YAML changes unsuccessfully (it seems like having custom tag !Include as a first entry in document is not the same as having it somewhere further along in the body of the document.

Comment: I updated my answer. Of course I could not use the proposed `>>` key as `>` starts a folded-style literal scalar %-)