# PyYAML error: Could not determine a constructor for the tag '!vault'

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ansible-vault

I am trying to read a YAML file that has the tag `!vault` in it. I get the error:

> could not determine a constructor for the tag '!vault'

Upon reading a couple of blogs, I understood that I need to specify some constructors to resolve this issue, but I'm not clear on how to do it.

```
import yaml
from yaml.loader import SafeLoader
    
with open('test.yml' ) as stream:
    try:
        inventory_info = yaml.safe_load(stream)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)

User = inventory_info['all']['children']['linux']['vars']['user']
key = inventory_info['all']['children']['linux']['vars']['key_file']
```

The YAML file I am using:

```
all:
  children:
    rhel:
      hosts: 172.18.144.98
    centos:
      hosts: 172.18.144.98  
    linux:
      children:
        rhel:
        centos:
      vars:
        user: "o9ansibleuser"
        key_file: "test.pem"
        ansible_password: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;2.1;AES256
          3234567899353936376166353
```

Comment: You need a constructor for this purpose. Therefore [Checkout this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058050/creating-custom-tag-in-pyyaml) for full usage!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use the `from_yaml` utility function:

```py
from ansible.parsing.utils.yaml import from_yaml

# inventory_info = yaml.safe_load(stream)  # Change this
inventory_info = from_yaml(stream)         # to this
```

Or add the constructor to `yaml.SafeLoader`:

```py
from ansible.parsing.yaml.objects import AnsibleVaultEncryptedUnicode


def construct_vault_encrypted_unicode(loader, node):
    value = loader.construct_scalar(node)
    return AnsibleVaultEncryptedUnicode(value)


yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor(u'!vault', construct_vault_encrypted_unicode)


inventory_info = yaml.safe_load(stream)
```

Comment: May I know which package to install for ansible.parsing.yaml.objects? I am getting an error saying  `No module named ansible.parsing.yaml.objects`

Comment: `pip install ansible`. Depending on how you intend to use `!vault`, you can also instantiate your own class.