# How can I parse YAML with TAGs?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a YAML document like this:

```yaml
 steps:
  - !<!entry>
    id: Entry-1
    actions: []
  - !<!replybuttons>
    id: ReplyButtons-langcheck
    footer: ''
  - !<!input>
    id: Input-langcheck
    var: Input-1
  - !<!logic>
    id: LangCheck-Logic
    entries:
      - condition: !<!equals>
          var: Input-langcheck
          isCaseSensitive: false
```

And I try to read it:

```py
import yaml

yaml.safe_load(yaml_text)
```

But I have an error:

```
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag '!entry'
```

How can I parse YAML with such tags?

This option also doesn't work.

```py
def construct_entry(loader, node):
    value = loader.construct_scalar(node)
    return value

yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor('!<!entry>', construct_entry)
result = yaml.safe_load(yaml_text)
```

If I try to use `ruamel.yaml` I can read the YAML documet, but I still don't understand how I can know about tags in python data.

```py
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML


class Entry:
    yaml_tag = '!<!entry>'

    def __init__(self, value, style=None):
        self.value = value
        self.style = style

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_scalar(cls.yaml_tag,
                                            u'{.value}'.format(node), node.style)

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        return cls(node.value, node.style)


yaml_text = """\
steps:
  - !<!entry>
    id: 1
    action: 2
  - !<!entry>
    id: 2
    action: 3
"""


yaml1 = YAML(typ='rt')

data1 = yaml1.load(yaml_text)

print(f'{data1=}')
yaml1.dump(data1, sys.stdout)

yaml2 = YAML(typ='rt')
yaml2.register_class(Entry)

data2 = yaml2.load(yaml_text)

print(f'{data2=}')
yaml1.dump(data2, sys.stdout)
```

The effect is exactly the same.

```
data1=ordereddict([('steps', [ordereddict([('id', 1), ('action', 2)]), ordereddict([('id', 2), ('action', 3)])])])
steps:
- !entry
  id: 1
  action: 2
- !entry
  id: 2
  action: 3
data2=ordereddict([('steps', [ordereddict([('id', 1), ('action', 2)]), ordereddict([('id', 2), ('action', 3)])])])
steps:
- !entry
  id: 1
  action: 2
- !entry
  id: 2
  action: 3
```

Comment: does the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69817464/pyyaml-error-could-not-determine-a-constructor-for-the-tag-vault fix your error message?

Comment: No. Same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YAML Error: could not determine a constructor for the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966633/yaml-error-could-not-determine-a-constructor-for-the-tag)

Comment: Create custom constructors as described in the linked post.

Comment: It seems there is no need to define a constructor for these tags if you are using `ruamel.yaml`.

Comment: @Duncan Do you just want to load, or do you need to dump the data and have it used by another program that expects `!<!entry>` ?

Comment: For the person that voted to close, this question is crucially different because it involves verbatim tags, and those need special handling not described in the proposed duplicate.

Comment: @0stone0 That answer you linked doesn't mention verbatim tags at all, so how could that apply?

Comment: @Anthon Yes, actually I need to dump the data. And I need the format like `!<!entry>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to inspect the tags and , the corresponding loaded
dict and list subclasses preserve
their tag in the `.tag` attribute (this might change so pin the version of ruamel.yaml you use):

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
steps:
- !<!entry>
  id: Entry-1
  actions: []
- !<!replybuttons>
  id: ReplyButtons-langcheck
  footer: ''
- !<!input>
  id: Input-langcheck
  var: Input-1
- !<!logic>
  id: LangCheck-Logic
  entries:
    - condition: !<!equals>
        var: Input-langcheck
        isCaseSensitive: false
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print('id', data['steps'][1]['id'])
print('tag', data['steps'][1].tag.value)
```

which gives:

```
id ReplyButtons-langcheck
tag !replybuttons
```

That your first attempt didn't work lies in the fact that your tags  are special because of the `<>`, these
are [verbatim tags](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#verbatim-tags), in this case necessary
to allow a tag starting with an exclamation mark. So when the YAML contains  `!<abc>`
you  register `!abc` with add_constructor (and I think you can leave out the !) and when your YAML contains `!<!abc>` you register `!abc`.
The parser strips the `<>` for these verbatim tags, that is why that printed tag
doesn't contain them after loading.

Writing this I noticed that the round-trip parser doesn't check if a tag needs
to be written verbatim. So if you dump the loaded data, you get non-verbatim tags,
which don't load the same way. So
if you need to update these files, then you should to get the classes registered (let me know
if that doesn't work out).
Recursively walking over the data structure and rewrite the tags to compensate for this bug
will not work as the `<>` gets escaped while dumping.

Comment: How can I dump verbatim tag like `!<!abc>`? Now if I dump a tag I have this `!%3C%21abc%3E`.

Comment: I was going to update my answer, but I see you already posted a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72256797/1307905), which I answered there