# How to create a custom YAML tag to read in a user designed class saved in a .yaml file

Tags: python, yaml

This is a bit of a two part question:

1. I have a user designed class where an instance is being saved in a yaml file. When I try to read in the file, I get the following error:

> "ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object:**main**.movement'
> in "test.yaml", line 1, column 1"

I have seen online that I need to design a custom constructor tag to help me read in the class but I have not been able to resolve this issue (I have been looking at https://death.andgravity.com/yaml-unknown-tag and [Creating Custom Tag in PyYAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058050/creating-custom-tag-in-pyyaml)).

My first question is therefore: how do I resolve this issue?

```
import yaml

#class
class movement:
    def __init__(self, ID, val):
        self.ID = ID
        self.val = val

#create class instance
m1 = movement('A', 10)

#save to yaml file
with open('test.yaml', 'w') as file:
    documents = yaml.dump(m1, file)
    
#read in yaml file
with open(r'test.yaml') as file:
    result = yaml.load(file, Loader=Loader)
    
print(type(result))
```

2. I wish to save multiple instance of the class into a yaml file and be able to load them in. Assuming that a solution exists for problem 1, what code would I need to add to be able to save multiple class instances in a single yaml file and to be able to read them all in.

Comment: assuming that [1] works, then you would just use a `for-loop` or `while-loop` to run this many times for each instance.

Comment: @David123 Welcome to SO. I edited your post to make the error more readable (click on the "edited ..." link above the username to the left of yours under the post to see what changed). Thanks are not necessary on SO, and should not be part of a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be looking at the YAML documentation on https://yaml.readthedocs.io. In
particular [Dumping Python classes](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumpcls.html)

I changed the name of your class to `Movement` (in Python we
typically [CapWord/CamelCase](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names) the class name).

```py
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, yaml_object

yaml = YAML()

@yaml_object(yaml)  # register with a particular YAML instance
class Movement:
    yaml_tag = '!Movement'

    def __init__(self, ID, val):
        self.ID = ID
        self.val = val

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Movement(ID={self.ID}, val={self.val})'

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_sequence(cls.yaml_tag, [node.ID, node.val])

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        data = Movement(None, None)
        yield data
        vals = constructor.construct_sequence(node)
        data.ID = vals[0]
        data.val = vals[1]

m1 = Movement('A', 10)

with open('test.yaml', 'wb') as file:
    yaml.dump(m1, file)
print(open('test.yaml').read(), '#############', sep='')
with open('test.yaml', 'rb') as file:
    data = yaml.load(file)
print(data)
```

which gives:

```
!Movement
- A
- 10
#############
Movement(ID=A, val=10)
```

There are a few things to note:

- `yaml.dump()` creates binary files (UTF-8 encoded), so open them `'rb'`/`'wb'` even
  if you currently have no non-ASCII characters.
- I printed the content of `test.yaml` so you can see the attributes of `Movement` are written as a sequence
- The `from_yaml` method is a generator. This is necessary because the attributes of `m1` could have an
  (indirect) self reference ( `m1.val = [42, m1]`, that not being a generator would result in an error.
- The `__repr__` method is there to facilitate printing a `Movement` instance.

If you have all your `Movement` instances up front, you can create a Python list of them and dump that.
More interesting is the case where you don't have them all (or cannot keep them in memory), or where the
instances are not related, in that case you should make a multi-document YAML file. In the following example
I dump the `Movement` class as a mapping instead of a sequence:

```py
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, yaml_object
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap

yaml = YAML()
yaml.explicit_start = True  # so you write complete documents
yaml.explicit_end = True

@yaml_object(yaml)  # register with a particular YAML instance
class Movement:
    yaml_tag = '!Movement'

    def __init__(self, ID=None, val=None):
        self.ID = ID
        self.val = val

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Movement(ID={self.ID}, val={self.val})'

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_mapping(cls.yaml_tag, node.__dict__)

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        data = Movement()
        yield data
        tmp = CommentedMap()
        constructor.construct_mapping(node, tmp)
        for k, v in tmp.items():
            setattr(data, k, v)

m1 = Movement('A', 10)
with open('test.yaml', 'wb') as file:
    yaml.dump(m1, file)
m2 = Movement('B')
m2.val = [42, m2]
with open('test.yaml', 'ab') as file:
    yaml.dump(m2, file)
print(open('test.yaml').read(), '#############', sep='')
with open('test.yaml', 'rb') as file:
    data = list(yaml.load_all(file))
print(data)
```

which gives:

```
--- !Movement
ID: A
val: 10
...
--- &id001 !Movement
ID: B
val:
- 42
- *id001
...
#############
[Movement(ID=A, val=10), Movement(ID=B, val=[42, Movement(ID=B, val=[...])])]
```

- dumping as a mapping makes it easier to extend the attributes of `Movement`
- you get two complete YAML documents in your file ( each between `---` and `...`
- you read all of the documents in the file using `load_all()`
- the self reference in `m2` is solved automatically for you with a YAML anchor and alias.
- to prevent the infinite loop print recursing down the loaded `m2` instance Python prints `val=[...]`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that step [1] of the question works (writing a class to a file, maybe you want to write the **repr** of the class to the file...), **but assuming it does**, then you would just need to create a dict of `ID`:`val` pairs and then loop through this dict sequentially.

I should point out that this only focuses on answering the question of how to achieve the repetitions, because there are errors in the actual code in the question.

For example `Loader` is not defined...

Here is the format of the code that would do this:
(i have marked the error).

```py
#class
class movement:
    def __init__(self, ID, val):
        self.ID = ID
        self.val = val

# make dict with contents (ID:val)
d = {'A':10, 'B':20, 'C':100, 'D':200}

for k,v in d.items():
    #create class instance
    m1 = movement(k, v)

    #save to yaml file
    file_name = f'test_{k}.yaml'
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
        documents = yaml.dump(m1, file)
        
    #read in yaml file
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        ### Warning: Loader is not defined, so this would be an error ###
        result = yaml.load(file, Loader=Loader)  
        
    print(type(result))
```

I will be interested to see if you can implement this...

Comment: The OP states "I wish to save multiple instance of the class into a yaml file" Although it reads "a" and not "one", I don't think one instance per file is the correct reading of that.

Comment: @Anthon,  yes,  to be fair, it was a bit ambiguous.  Nevertheless, the OP could replace the class for the `val` if that was the case...